# Web api testing could not use ApiSuiteLoader

Tags: magento2, error, rest-api, api-functional-tests

I am new to testing in Magento. To add a new functional api test, I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAA7BkH82gY&ab_channel=MaxPronko but he doesn't show how he runs the test.

I followed the instructions of Magento and ran this command:

> vendor/bin/phpunit --config ./dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml

But I get this error. And I dont't know how to fix it

> PHPUnit 9.1.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Could not use "Magento\TestFramework\ApiSuiteLoader" as loader.
>
> === Memory Usage System Stats === Memory usage (OS):  56.30M (201.07% of 28.00M reported by PHP) Estimated memory leak:   28.30M (50.27% of
> used memory)

How can I solve this problem? or is there another solution to run the web api functional tests?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Magento core bug. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32252.
Quick fix is to comment out the following line

```
chdir(BP . '/dev/tests/integration');
```

in dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Application.php

Comment: I commented out that line but now I get the following error:
'''
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Could not read "".

/var/www/osp.example.com/magento-headless/Magento2/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/WebApiTest.php:32

  thrown in /var/www/osp.example.com/magento-headless/Magento2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Xml.php on line 129

=== Memory Usage System Stats ===
Memory usage (OS): 61.90M (193.44% of 32.00M reported by PHP)
Estimated memory leak: 29.90M (48.31% of used memory)
'''

Do you know, how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

have the same issue.
For some reason stream_resolve_include_path in vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php::handleLoader returns false.
I did a temporary workaround: added an extra statement if it's false, then set path to file.