# phpunit.rest.xml fatal error could not read ""

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, webapi, api-functional-tests

I am trying to run the Magento web api tests by running the following command:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --config ./dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml
```

But it gives this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Could not read "".

/var/www/osp.example.com/magento-headless/Magento2/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/WebApiTest.php:39
/var/www/osp.example.com/magento-headless/Magento2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:61

  thrown in /var/www/osp.example.com/magento-headless/Magento2/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Xml.php on line 135
```

After a lot of debugging, I see that WebpApiTest.php runs the function `getConfigurationFile` which gives back an empty string. This is the code of that function:

```
    /**
     * Returns config file name from command line params.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private static function getConfigurationFile(): string
    {
        $params = getopt('c:', ['configuration:']);

        $longConfig = $params['configuration'] ?? '';
        $shortConfig = $params['c'] ?? '';

        return $shortConfig ? $shortConfig : $longConfig;
    }
```

I don't really get what its doing and which information it is supposed to return.
Can anyone check what kinda information it is supposed to return? Maybe then I can fix it and run the webapi tests of Magento 2.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file *./dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml* exist?

Magento includes ".dist" versions of configuration files for certain tools. The first step to using them is to make a copy without the ".dist" extension (thus preserving the original as a backup/reference).

Comment: Yes that file does exist and I edited it so the TEST_BASE_URL is the right Magento instance URL. I followed the steps on the Magento website: [https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/web-api-functional-testing.html]

Comment: It looks like the error here goes back to this open bug, https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32252, and the fix suggested there and here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/337046/web-api-testing-could-not-use-apisuiteloader (which evidently does not resolve the original problem).

Comment: Does not work, after commenting out ' chdir(BP . '/dev/tests/integration');' I still get the same error of my original question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like PHPUnit tries to find a file named after the name-attribute of the testsuite-tag

1. if it either cannot find any tests (wrong naming or wrong directory)
2. here is a fatal error occuring in a test-script; which occures so early that PHPUnit cannot identify the content of that file as a test - as no class could be loaded up until that point.